# Hide a signature in the Show

Tags: hide, signature, alloy

Can I hide a inused signature when I show the model(when I execute the line "pred show{}
run show for 8")?
For inused signature, I mean the signature which are not connected by no arrow.

For example:

abstract sig TypeMessage{}

one sig RichiestaLogin, RichiestaRegistrazione, RichiestaShell

Not going into the details of my code, there are instances in which I use a message type and other instances in which their use, so that some istances remain unconnected.
I would not show those instances are not connected in my diagram of the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want them in your model, constrain your model (or probably better the 'show' predicate) to exclude models which have unconnected atoms (where 'connected' means whatever you want it to mean).

If you really want to allow them in the model instances, but exclude them just from the display, you can define a subset of TypeMessage which contains just those TypeMessage atoms which are not connected.  Then customize your display theme to suppress display of members of that set.

If the only problem is that you find the unconnected atoms distracting, I'd try to learn not to be distracted by them.

Comment: I don't want them in my model.
I try a constrain in the 'show' predicate but I could not beacause I'm in the early of the Alloy's programmation.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, if you don't want them in your model, then your desires and your model are in conflict: your model specifies that you want exactly one of each of the message types RichiestaLogin, RichiestaRegistrazione, and RichiestaShell.  If you want to allow models with no atoms of those types, you need to specify `lone` and not `one`.